# Python and Matlab: transform a python dict into a struct or cell array (if possible)

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, user-defined-functions

I have a python function that returns a dictionary with the contents of a Dataframe. I want to get that data into a struct or cell array in Python for further manipulation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def test(w,j,l):
    array1 = np.array([w,j,l])
    array2 = np.array(['a','b','c'])
    array3 = np.array([1.01,2.02,3.03])
    df = pd.DataFrame({'array1':array1, 'array2':array2,'array3':array3})
    return df.to_dict()
```

I call it in Matlab like this:

```
N = py.py2mat.test(2,4,5);
S = struct(N);
```

The result I get is a py.dict (as expected), after that I just use struct(N) and that's it. The issue here is, that inside the structure I get a bunch of nested dictionaries. I can't try workarounds like, let's say transforming the dictionary into a string to use [jsondecode][1]. Although I can find values by indexing the struct, for instance, saying S.array1{1} gives me 4, and I can call the len() python function to get a sense of the dimension of the array... I would like to know if there's another workaround to this.

There are some Python-2-Matlab interfaces around there (it will not hurt me to learn which one is most preferred for these situations), but that's not exactly what I'm looking for either, though I could settle with that (or building a loop to fill another struct given that I can learn the dimensions of the array).

Is there any other way for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have similar problems. The MATLAB supports the basic data structure but NUMPY. You may think it is fair because this interface is not designed for a special package. If MATLAB supports NUMPY, what about TENSORFLOW? But, the consequence of the standard tactical thinking is a bad user experience. Once I sent a NUMPY array to MATLAB, I had to use four lines. `eng = matlab.engine.connect_matlab()
Figs = Figs.tolist()
Figs = matlab.uint8(Figs)
eng.workspace[MAT_Var_Name] = Figs
` When I got it back from the MATLAB, I did another three lines.

Comment: `eng = matlab.engine.connect_matlab()
Figs = eng.workspace[MAT_Var_Name]
AFig = np.array(Figs,dtype=np.uint8)
` The most unbelievable thing is that this procedure is very slow. Can we just transform the address of the data?